# How to import file as text into vite.config.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I have simple scss file in my project directory and I wanna get it's content on the compiling stage so I could transform in on vite.config.js
but how can I get it's content?
I mean I'm able to get content using

```js
import test from "./src/extensions/sites/noscript/test.css";
console.log(test);
```

in App.vue
but that doesn't work in vite.config.js (that works with webpack)
Is there any ways to get file content?
test == {} when I'm debugging... vite.config.js
and works well in App.vue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vite.config.js` is run as a Node script, so you could use [`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options) to read the file from disk into a string:

```js
// vite.config.js
import fs from 'fs'

const styleRaw = fs.readFileSync('./src/extensions/sites/noscript/test.css', 'utf-8')
console.log(styleRaw)
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-import-asset-as-string-2uv3qx?file=vite.config.js)